# Count how many times a functions is called, with different parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that receives an int as a parameter:

```
function addToCart(id){
    var cart= cart.info;
    for( i = 0; i < cart.length; i++){
        // SOME CODE
    }
}
```

The ID, that the addToCart function is receiving, is a number that other stuff on the shop got.
For example, it will receive 3 if the user select movie, or 2 if the user selects computers etc.

All of that works, but what I want is it to count how many times a user have called on the movies for example, or computers. So when they view the shopping cart it will stand "You have selected movies X times". Is there an easy way to do so?

EDIT #1

```
var test1= {
    test: [
        {
            name: "Test1",
            image: "..",
            info: "Test1",
            price: 159.50
        }, {
            name: "Test2",
            image: "..",
            info: "Test2",
            price: 159.50
        }, {
            name: "Test3",
            image: "..",
            info: "Test3",
            price: 159.50
        }, {
            name: "Test4",
            image: "..",
            info: "Test4",
            price: 159.50
        } 
    ]   
}
```

For-loop:

```
for( i = 0; i < test1.length; i++){
    if(id == [i]){
        if($("#testDiv" + [i]).length == 0) {
            $("#stuff").append('<div id="test1'+ [i] +'"></div>');
            $("#test1" + [i]).append('//WRITE OUT INFO ABOUT JSON-object');
            $("#test1" + [i]).append('//WRITE OUT INFO ABOUT JSON-object');
            $("#test1" + [i]).append('//WRITE OUT INFO ABOUT JSON-object');
        } 
    }
}
```

The for-loop is inside of the addToCart, and the Jquery-stuff inside the forloop runs if an user add things to the cart. But, only if the div ID not exist. If it exist then I need to count how many times the item have been clicked.

With this method I get it to work:

```
if([i]  == 0){
                    test1Sum++;
                    $("#total" + [i] ).html(test1Sum);
                } else if([i]  == 1) {
                    test2Sum++;
                    $("#total" + [i] ).html(test2Sum);
                } else if ([i]  == 2){
                    test3Sum++;
                    $("#total" + [i] ).html(test3Sum);
                } else if ([i] == 3){
                    test4Sum++;
                    $("#total" + [i] ).html(test4Sum);
                }
```

But is there any better way to do so? Because for each new object I add to the JSon list I'll have to write a new else if - statement

Comment: on cart adding save ids in a hidden field and count them at last

Comment: @EhsanSajjad why a hidden field? A simple variable would do.

Comment: It seems to me that you should be looping over `test1.test.length` not just `test.length` based on your newly added code. The rest of what you're doing isn't all that clear though.

Answer (score 1):

```
var counters = { movies: 0, computers: 0 };

if(id === 3){
   counters.movies +=1;
}
```

Edit the above to include all of the cases and display it to your user after. This will keep separate counts for each of your IDs.

Comment: if after adding user removes from cart then?

Comment: var counters = { movies: 0, computers: 0 } may be better...but yeah.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad if a user removes an item from the cart then decrement your counter.

Comment: @PrisonerZERO I made the edit, is that what you're going for?

Comment: This work, but is it possible to get out ID from JSON object? I have everything stored into a JSON-list and then uses an for-loop to get which [i] they are stored at. But I make it work manually, but It would be great if it will work dynamicly.

Comment: @Emil edit your question to include your JSON and the loop you're trying to create and I will look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Sure

```
var ids = ["","","computers","movies"];
cart.counter = {};
function addToCart(id) {
  if (cart.counter[ids[id]]!=null) cart.counter[ids[id]]++;
  else cart.counter[ids[id]]=0;
  var msg ="";
  for (var tp in cart.counter) {
    msg+="\nYou called "+ tp + ":"+cart.counter[tp])
  }
  alert(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one global function counter or counter specific to your scope and use caller method.

```
var func_counter=0;

function addToCart() {


   if (addToCart.caller == null) {
      return ("The function was called from the top!");
   } else
      func_counter++;
      return WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_TO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a count of each type of item in the shopping cart. If you have a single page for viewing shopping cart contents, something like this could work:

```
var itemCount = {};

function addToCart(id){
    var productName = getName(id); // you will need to implement this

    if(itemCount[productName] != null)
        itemCount[productName]++;
    else
        itemCount[productName] = 0; // initialize

    alert('You have ' + itemCount[productName] + ' ' + productName + '(s) in your cart');
}

function removeFromCart(id) {
    var productName = getName(id); // you will need to implement this

    if(itemCount[productName] != null)
        if(itemCount[productName] > 0)
            itemCount[productName]--;
    else
        itemCount[productName] = 0;

    alert('You have ' + itemCount[productName] + ' ' + productName + '(s) in your cart');
}
```

You'll need to implement the product name lookup, but by using the bracket notation for object properties, you can dynamically initialize and update product counts in your cart.

Comment: you need to initialise the counter

Answer (score 0):

you can make an array:

```
var items = new Array();

function addToCart(id){
     items.push(id)


}
```

and on item removing from Cart, remove it:

```
 items.pop(id);
```

Get the total number of selected movies like this:

```
var total = item.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

```
var TotalCheck= {}
    // Checks if a item exist
        if($("#totals" + [i]).length !== 0){
            TotalCheck["something" + [i]]++;
            $("#totals" + [i]).html(TotalCheck["something" + [i]]);
        }
```

And then I have this in my shopping cart so get how many how items that I have in cart

```
$("#totals" + [i]).html(TotalCheck["something" + [i]] = 1);
```